# Minor inconsistency in Fit/Log

Tags: fitting

I was trying to fit a powerlaw to some data and noticed some inconsistency in the behaviour of mathematica.

This works

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Fit[#, {1, Log[r]}, Log[r]] & // Exp
```

(* r *)

whereas this does not

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Fit[#, {1, Log10[r]}, Log10[r]] & // 10^# &
```

[image]

> While I understand the logic, it seems it represents some level of inconsistency between the way the variables are handled by `Fit`?

Comment: Wow, it's a bit surprising to me the first sample works.

Comment: @xzczd I agree, but its also unfortunate both do not behave the same way (?)

Comment: To be on the safe side, you should fit relative to a variable not an expression. That the first example works is really a surprise.

Comment: I think the first one only works for the same reason that e.g. `a[1]` is generally allowed to be considered a "variable" in functions like these—`Log[r]` just happens to be of the same form. Its "meaning" as a logarithm isn't seen by `Fit`. (However, `Log10[r]` immediately evaluates to `Log[r]/Log[10]`, and so is not recognized as a variable.)